# SSL certificate for server with 2 static ips

Tags: apache, security-certificate

We have an apache server in our office premises which is used for some ssl related requests. The office premise has 2 internet connections with static ip address. The internet connections are switched based on load and availability automatically by a hardware firewall and router.
The port forwarding is set correctly for the same.

The problem we are facing is that we need to change the SSL certificate on the server based on the ip address which is currently in use(which changes at average frequency of 1 day). Is there some automatic way in which we can use the correct SSL certificate depending on the ip address in use?

Comment: So we could as well assume that you have a dynamic IP?

Comment: No it is not a dynamic ip it is 2 static ips, so a hardcoded solution will also work in which we can run some batch script to change the certificate.

Comment: Two static IP's that change from time to time?

Comment: Yes, automatically so that internet can be switched seamlessly without any obstruction due to network failures.

Comment: Yes, so we could assume your IP is dynamic.

Comment: The solution does not have to factor whole set of dynamic addresses and can be based on some failure mechanism which just changes the server certificate to the other one.

Comment: Do you understand why hes asking you if they are Dynamic?  If they were truly static you would be in control of them.  No script or fix anyone here gives you will work on a dynamic address as your ISP controls those.

Comment: But the ip addresses are static and we are ourselves switching between them using automated hardware firewall

Comment: Then why cant you buy two SSL certs?

Comment: We have 2 ssl certs but how can we provide both at a time to the external requests

Answer (score 1):

Apache can be configured to serve different SSL for each of your IP addresses.  To do so, you need to set up Virtual hosts for each IP address on port 433.  For example:

```
Listen 2.2.2.2:443
Listen 3.3.3.3:443

<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:443>
    ServerName secure.com
    DocumentRoot /home/foo/secure.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/foo/ssl/secure.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/foo/ssl/secure.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/foo/ssl/ca.txt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 3.3.3.3:443>
    ServerName secure.net
    DocumentRoot /home/foo/secure.net
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/foo/ssl/secure.net.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/foo/ssl/secure.net.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/foo/ssl/ca.txt
</VirtualHost>
```